# blazor quickgrid sorting not working for when sencond request clicked or selected or not getting refreshed quickgrid table data on selecting different

Tags: sorting, selection-sort, selectionchanged, quickgrid

```
<QuickGrid TGridItem="DataRow" @ref ="Grid" Items="@rows.AsQueryable()" Pagination="@pagination">
    @foreach (var col in columns)
    {
       <PropertyColumn Property="@(c=>c[col.ColumnName])" Sortable="true" Title="@col.ColumnName">
       </PropertyColumn>        
    }


</QuickGrid>
<sub>
when I apply sortable = "ture", the sencond request in breaking by givning below runtime expection

Error: System.ArgumentException: Column 'Id' does not belong to table .
   at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName)
   at System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.ComputeMap(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator(Int32 minIdx, Int32 maxIdx)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid.QuickGrid`1.ResolveItemsRequestAsync(GridItemsProviderRequest`1 request)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid.QuickGrid`1.RefreshDataCoreAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
log @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:1 Information: Connection disconnected.
```

*********Explanation***********
sorting does not work on selecting different table data, sorting should work when I select different table data and Quick grid get refresh according to the selection of table data.
*******************************end ***************************************